# Can you achieve a case insensitive 'unique' constraint in Sqlite3 (with Django)?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models

So let's say I'm using Python 2.5's built-in default sqlite3 and I have a Django model class with the following code:

```
class SomeEntity(models.Model):
    some_field = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_index=True, unique=True)
```

I've got the admin interface setup and everything appears to be working fine except that I can create two SomeEntity records, one with some_field='some value' and one with some_field='Some Value' because the unique constraint on some_field appears to be case sensitive.

Is there some way to force sqlite to perform a case *in*sensitive comparison when checking for uniqueness?

I can't seem to find an option for this in Django's docs and I'm wondering if there's something that I can do directly to sqlite to get it to behave the way I want. :-)

Comment: In order to avoid duplicate answers, maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300202/make-case-insensitive-tags-with-django-taggit/6409256#6409256) can put you on the right track?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes this can easily be done by adding a unique index to the table with the following command:

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uidxName ON mytable (myfield COLLATE NOCASE)

If you need case insensitivity for nonASCII letters, you will need to register your own COLLATION with commands similar to the following:

The following example shows a custom collation that sorts “the wrong way”:

```
import sqlite3

def collate_reverse(string1, string2):
    return -cmp(string1, string2)

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
con.create_collation("reverse", collate_reverse)

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("create table test(x)")
cur.executemany("insert into test(x) values (?)", [("a",), ("b",)])
cur.execute("select x from test order by x collate reverse")
for row in cur:
    print row
con.close()
```

Additional python documentation for sqlite3 shown [here](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html)

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you can create and use a custom model field; it would be a subclass of CharField but providing a [db_type](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#db_type) method returning "text collate nocase"

Comment: Interesting, but COLLATE NOCASE only provides case insensitivity for ASCII letters.  No matter, I'm only using sqlite for the prototype and not the final product.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone in 2021, with the help of [Django 4.0 UniqueConstraint expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/4.0/#functional-unique-constraints) you could add a Meta class to your model like this:

```py
class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(
            Lower('<field name>'),
            name='<constraint name>'
        ),
    ]
```