# make case-insensitive tags with django-taggit

Tags: django, django-taggit

I added tags = TaggableManager(blank=True) to my models, but I want my tags to be case-insensitive.
I saw some snippets of work arounds for this and wanted to ask if there is an easy way to do it?
If I have to override some methods from the TaggableManager, please advise how can I do that?

Thanks in advance,
Arshavski Alexander.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have used [this snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/305/) for a similar issue. A copy of the code (reprinted for posterity):

```
from django.db.models import Manager
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet

class CaseInsensitiveQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def _filter_or_exclude(self, mapper, *args, **kwargs):
        # 'name' is a field in your Model whose lookups you want case-insensitive by default
        if 'name' in kwargs:
            kwargs['name__iexact'] = kwargs['name']
            del kwargs['name']
        return super(CaseInsensitiveQuerySet, self)._filter_or_exclude(mapper, *args, **kwargs)

# custom manager that overrides the initial query set
class TagManager(Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return CaseInsensitiveQuerySet(self.model)

# and the model itself
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(maxlength=50, unique=True, db_index=True)

    objects = TagManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
# now...
>>> tag = Tag(name='test')
>>> tag.save()
>>> Tag.objects.get(name='TEST')
<Tag: test>
```

Basically, you override the initial queryset so that all querysets take case insensitivity into account.

Comment: Please don't post the exact same answer multiple times. If the question is a duplicate, flag it as such.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.  The question involves django-taggit.  Your suggestion is basically "write your own tagging app".

Answer (score 3):

I am sure you have figured out solution by now :) Though I will put the answer as someone might hit this while searching -

Use https://github.com/shacker/django-taggit version of django-taggit.

It allows to configure TAGGIT_FORCE_LOWERCASE = True

It also allows you to filter stop words.

Comment: Does this go into `settings.py` or `models.py`?

Comment: Rusl, it would go in your `settings.py`

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of django-taggit support a `TAGGIT_CASE_INSENSITIVE` setting, that should behave the way you're describing.

Comment: Does this go into `settings.py` or `models.py`?

Comment: @rusl settings.py

Answer (score 0):

According to _TaggableManager on 211 line

```
case_insensitive = getattr(settings, "TAGGIT_CASE_INSENSITIVE", False)
```

we need to add this parameter in settings.py