# How to force Django to do a case sensitive comparison?

Tags: mysql, django

Because of the way our databases are collated they ignore case for usernames and passwords, which we're currently unable to fix at the database level. It appears from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936967/mysql-case-insensitive-select) that `WHERE BINARY 'something' = 'Something'` should fix the problem, but I haven't been able to figure out to get Django to insert `BINARY`. Any tips?

Comment: Just as a side note, you shouldn't store passwords in your database without running them through `sha1` or some other hashing function.

Comment: Good point, but we still need case sensitivity for usernames.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you achieve a case insensitive 'unique' constraint in Sqlite3 (with Django)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276656/can-you-achieve-a-case-insensitive-unique-constraint-in-sqlite3-with-django)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an easy way to force Django to add something into a query content.

You may want to simply write a [raw SQL query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/) within the Django to get objects filtered with case-sensitive comparison and then use them in normal queries.

The other approach is to use Django case-sensitive filters in order to achieve the same result. E.g. `contains`/`startswith` both use `BINARY LIKE` and may be used while comparing two strings with the same length (like a password hash)). Finally, you can use `regexp` to do the case-sensitive comparison. But these are rather ugly methods in that situation. They have an uncessary overhead and you should avoid them as long as it's possible.